# jQuery validation custom animation for errorPlacement

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, validation

OK so I have a form with 1 required field. This is the validation code:

```
$('#form').validate({
    rules: {
        email: {
            required: true,
            email: true
        }
    },
    messages: {
        email: "Please enter a valid email address."
    },
    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
        error.appendTo(element.parent()).hide().fadeIn;
    }
 });
```

This is great, except I want the animation to be of a slidedown flavor. Which brings up an interesting point: trying to remove the fadeIn, it doesn't even hide the element. Once the error is corrected, I want it to slide away, and upon successful submission, I want a success message to slideDown. Can I get some help? I've seen a lot of people suggest non-working stuff but no real suggestion for a fix.

Answer (score -1):

As for the success piece, add your slideDown() funcationality to the success option within your call to validate.

```
success: function() {
 $('#foo').slideDown(); //slide down your success element
}
```

As for the fadeIn - I am not certain that entire line looks correct, but straight off it is at least missing some parentheses after `fadeIn()`;

Comment: That's fine but that really doesn't entirely help me. I just rewrote the code because I can't post our internal code. The fadeIn works but slideDown doesn't because what I'm assuming is the nature of the plugin. I can't insert those errors hidden.... .hide() doesn't work.